# Prove that an integral is real and ignore complex parts

Tags: sequences-and-series

(This question comes from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-pXwWNcsbc&list=PLQS0ppnXeKER066aOXuVmaAMBSwJ7Cxz2&index=2) video)

Imagine we are trying to solve the integral :

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln(2\cos x)\,dx$$
This integral is defined on the real numbers. However, if I decide to use eulers complex cosine formula ($\cos \theta = \frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$), I can reduce the integral to this (this is shown in the video) :

$$ I = \frac{i\pi^2}{8} - i( 1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\frac{1}{9^2}+\cdots)$$

As you can the the result found this way is a pure imaginary number. In the video, it is then explained that since the integral is defined on the real numbers, therefor the complex result is simply a "residue" of the calculations. My question is, is this reasoning valid ? If not, what could bring us to the same result, that $I = 0$ (I doubt the youtube video would assume something wrong)

I turns out that the result is correct and saying that the result is equal to zero
means that $1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\frac{1}{9^2}+\cdots = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$. We can the continue and use this result to show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: When dealing with complex numbers, it's better to avoid using $i$ as a summation index.

Comment: I edited the summation to be more comprehensible.

Comment: Which "the same result"? That the integral is $0$?

Comment: Yes, that the integral is equal to zero

Comment: The video looks okay.  The results $\frac{\pi^2}{8}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ can also be found via Fourier series.

Comment: Observe that the derivation in the video did not ignore the complex part. Quite opposite: it heavily used it and due to this obtained quite non-trivial result. :)

Comment: What I meant is that he simply considered the real part to be the answer and not the imaginary. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: He indeed used the fact that the integral of real-valued function is real. This follows from the additivity of  integrals.

Comment: I didn't understand how this is connected can you expand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can prove the integration result by pure real methods.

First using the substitution $t=\frac\pi2-x$ observe:
$$
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(2\cos x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(2\sin x)dx.
$$

Next add both above integrals to obtain
$$\begin{align}
2I&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(4\cos x\sin x)dx\tag1\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(2\sin 2x)dx\tag2\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(2\sin 2x)dx\tag3\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(2\sin t)dt\tag4\\
&=I
\end{align}$$
where we used:

1. $\log a+\log b=\log(ab)$
2. $2\cos x\sin x=\sin 2x$
3. $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$
4. $x\mapsto \frac t2$

Finally:
$$2I=I\implies I=0.
$$